# Error from bibtex

Tags: pdftex, incompatibility

I want to upload my academic paper to a journal. In my home system, I run pdflatex and bibtex to build the pdf and everything is fine.

The submission website, requires all source files including `.eps`, `.cls`, `.bst`, `.bib` and `.tex` files. During the build process, it fails to create the PDF and what I understand from the log file is that it uses `PDFTEX` instead of `PDFLATEX`. See this log

```
TexLaTex Conversion Log for cj.tex

Step 0. TeX fileset relationship parsing:
File cj.tex determined to be root TeX file
File comjnl.cls determined to be a resource for cj.tex
File array determined to be a resource for cj.tex
File processors.eps determined to be a resource for cj.tex
<SOME OTHER EPS FILES> 
File compj.bst determined to be a resource for cj.tex
File mybibfile.bib determined to be a resource for cj.tex

Step 1. Conversion From .tex to .dvi Format:

Conversion Pass Number 1

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=latex 2012.7.19)  13 MAR 2015 05:11
entering extended mode
...
...
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 69
while$ -- 148
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 469
(There was 1 error message)
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: cj.aux
The style file: compj.bst
Database file #1: mybibfile.bib
I was expecting an "="---line 49 of file mybibfile.bib
 :   number 
 :          "2"
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--empty address in Callahan91
....
....
(There was 1 error message)
Error running the command (bibtex cj.aux) from the directory (/shared/gus/docfiles/prod1/compj/2015/03/19897503/docfiles/tex)

Command Log results:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=latex 2012.7.19)  13 MAR 2015 05:11
entering extended mode
...
...
```

Please note the error statement `Error running the command (bibtex cj.aux) from the directory`.

How should I make my tex files compatible with PDFTEX?

Comment: No, it's running LaTeX, not pdfTeX. The error seems to be coming from BibTeX.

Comment: When I run `pdftex` command, I also get an error but that is `Undefined control sequence. l.1 \documentclass`. SO I thought there is a problem with pdftex

Comment: Sure, pdfTeX *must* be run on plain TeX files, not on LaTeX files.

Comment: The error message is not from latex and says that there is a syntax error in your bib file at line 49. The usual reason for bibtex reporting syntax errors in bib files is that they have a syntax error. Post the the first 60 or so lines of `mybibfile.bib`

Comment: The posted error says you have written `number "2"` in you `bib` file instead of `number="2"`

Comment: So, why didn't I see any problem on my home machine? the final pdf file is available in my machine

Comment: OK you are right. I wonder why I didn't get any error on my machine. Also, in the log it said "I was expecting". Shouldn't simply write an error message `syntax error at line`???!!!

Comment: I;m not sure what is causing the error but rather than uploading the bibtex file I recommend including the `bbl` file for the paper directly into the tex file (i.e. include it "by hand"). This is what I always do, both for journal submission and for my less tex-literate coauthors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is from `bibtex`.
As the message states there is a missing `=` sign in your `.bib` file.
You have written in some entry

```
number "2",
```

instead of

```
number="2",
```

On the other hand, for many journal systems I find it is more reliable to include the `.bbl` data in the main file, so that a `bibtex` processing stage is not needed on their site.